# How to show a common button in all the tabs in a TabBar based application in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, uibutton, uitabbarcontroller, uiwindow

I have a **TabBar based application** with 5 tabs. My requirement is to have a **common button in all the tabs**. Each tab is a separate view controller. On click of a button inside a view controller in the 3rd tab, i am transitioning(coming back) to the root view controller of 3rd tab. Here i wanted to have a button in the root view controller to go back to the view controller. And i want this button to be shown in all the tabs whenever the user changes the tabs. Do i need to add the button to the UIWindow and show it in all the tabs? Do i need to add a button in all the root view controllers for all the tabs individually? What would be the best design approach to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

#### You can put this code in appDelegate Method

This Method for Creating Bottom View to add button

```
-(void)CreateBottomView
{
    viewBottom = [[UIView alloc]init];
    viewBottom.frame = CGRectMake(0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height-46,[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width , 46);
    [self.window addSubview:viewBottom];

    UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, viewBottom.frame.size.width, viewBottom.frame.size.height)];
    image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bottem-trip-bg.png"];

    UIButton *btnHome = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    btnHome.frame =CGRectMake([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width / 2 - 19, 4 , 39,38);
    [btnHome setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"home-icon.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btnHome addTarget:self action:@selector(OnClickHome) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [viewBottom addSubview:image];
    [viewBottom addSubview:btnHome];
}
```

#### This methods for show and hide view as per you requirement

```
-(void)ShowBottomView
{
      viewBottom.frame = CGRectMake(0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height-46,[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width , 46);
}

-(void)HideBottomView
{
     viewBottom.frame = CGRectMake(0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height+20,[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width , 46);
}
```

I hope this will Help you

Comment: What does "OnCLickHome" Button does here? Do we need to call the ShowBottomView and HideBottonView in the viewcontrollers in viewWillAppear methods?

Comment: It will reach at main view controller. 
-(void)OnClickHome
{
    for (UIViewController *controller in self.navigationController.viewControllers)
    {
        if ([controller isKindOfClass:[HomeView class]])
        {
            [self.navigationController popToViewController:controller animated:YES];
            break;
        }
    }
}

Comment: "OnClickHome" button is present in the AppDelegate and why will it be called in the main view controller? Is there a delegate approach here? But i dont see anything as such in the code mentioned above?

Comment: Its a common button click event which you use in all view controller